# Результат запроса в виде ассоциативного массива

Tags: алгоритм, php

Пробую написать свой драйвер баз данных типа mysql, хочу что бы в `$data['user_name']` записывался результат работы запроса в виде ас. массива, идей много, хочу услышать мнения экспертов:

```
    public static function select($query)
    {
        mysql_query($query) or die($logs->write(mysql_error()));
    }
```

вызываю так

```
    if(isset(parent::$id))
    {
        $data['user_name'] = mysql :: select("SELECT `login` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = '". parent::$id ."'");
    }
```

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не эксперт, конечно, но вот с таким, я думаю, многие согласятся.

```
public static function select() {
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die($logs->write(mysql_error()));
  if ( !mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
    return false;
  }
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Comment: то что я хотел, спасибо